# Why don't C++ Game Developers use the boost library?

Tags: c++

So if you spend any time viewing / answering questions over on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) under the C++ tag, you will quickly notice that just about *everybody* uses the [boost](http://www.boost.org/) library; some would even say that if you aren't using it, you're not writing "real' C++ (I disagree, but that's not the point).

But then there is the game industry, which is well known for using C++ and *not* using boost.  I can't help but wonder why that is.  I don't care to use boost because I write games (now) as a hobby, and part of that hobby is implementing what I need when I am able to and using off-the-shelf libraries when I can't.  But that is just me.

Why don't game developers, in general, use the boost library?  Is it performance or memory concerns?  Style?  Something Else?

I was about to ask this on stack overflow, but I figured the question is better asked here.

EDIT :

I realize I can't speak for all game programmers and I haven't seen all game projects, so I can't say game developers *never* use boost; this is simply my experience.

Allow me to edit my question to also ask, if you do use boost, why did you choose to use it?

Comment: related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/268/stl-for-games-yea-or-nay

Comment: Would it be fair to say that "Boost" is far too large a collection of libraries to make "use boost" or "don't use boost" a fair choice?  Even Google restricts to a small subset of "boost" in their standards I believe.

Comment: Game binaries are already massive enough.

Comment: @Tetrad STL is not boost, and STL is heavily used in gamedev.

Comment: I really don't see where the question is "not constructive", this would need explaining.

Comment: @DanOlson https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html .. you can extract only what you need from boost

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Some developers do, some developers don't (in games and elsewhere). It depends on what the needs/requirements of those developers are, and what existing technology they have to leverage.

C++'s standard library is often given the same treatment, and people often wonder the same thing you are wondering about *it*, too. Most of the reasons are similar, for example:

- A developer may already have an in-house library of functionality that provides the same services that the standard library or Boost provides. Such in-house libraries were often written long ago, when implementation support for the standard library was weak and Boost was basically non-existent, so they more-or-less *had* to be written. In this scenario, it's usually not really worth transitioning away from the in-house functionality -- it would be a major porting effort that would destabilize a lot of code, and provide almost no benefit.
- A developer may be working on platforms where compiler support for the advanced C++ techniques leveraged by Boost are not well supported, such that the Boost code doesn't compile at all or performs quite poorly. This applies to the standard library as well, although much less so these days.
- Boost and the language's standard library are general purpose, and while that is fine and good for most applications, sometimes a developer has specific needs that can be better addressed by more specialized containers.

I think the above are two reasonable reasons, although there are certainly others. You have to be careful though because many reasons for avoiding Boost, the standard libraries, or whatever boil down to "not invented here" syndrome, which *can* be an indication that the reason isn't very well grounded in practical realities.

Also remember that the needs of a large-ish studio are usually very different from the needs of an individual developer. For example, an individual developer probably has less legacy code floating around to maintain and so perhaps porting from a home-grown version of the Boost or standard library functionality will not be as big of a time sink and will save that developer from having to maintain that code as extensively in the future -- thus invalidating my first bullet point.

In the end, it is all about evaluating your requirements and time investiture against your desired goal and determining which option meets your needs the best. Developers who aren't using Boost or the standard library have usually done so and reached that conclusion -- perhaps you will too, and perhaps not.

Comment: Another point - some companies don't use Boost because of it's negative impact on compilation speed in a highly interative development environment.

Answer (score 32):

**Edit Coming Back to This Question After A Few Years**
Having continued to use more and more boost libraries, I thought I'd update this question to give a solid case for why you should use boost when the description of the product matches your desired functionality. This will convince even nay-sayers. Download openSSL, try to make a client and server application with it. Now try and make that work on every platform. Then, download and use boost::asio::ssl to make the same application. If you're not convinced that boost is the right place to look for clean, well optimized, peer reviewed, cross-platform code, this simple exercise will convert you.

**Tl;dr version:**

In my opinion, you don't see a ton of indie or small to mid size development firms using boost because it's a massive and powerful wild beast that isn't easy to tame and you're basically on your own when trying to learn how to use it. The documentation is lacking in a few ways (see long version) and "the community" around the project either seems to be missing, scattered or inactive (compared to other projects).

**Very Long Winded Version:**
I realize there is already an accepted answer but as someone who actually uses boost in nearly every project I do, I thought I'd post an answer.

I remember when I first got poking around in boost and honestly I had no frigging idea what was happening. Boost is not very well documented at all. People might disagree with me on that I'm sure because there are tons of snippets of example code and a comments and such, but it is all very cold and vague as well as difficult to navigate.

Also it seems difficult to find any place where you feel like you've found "the community" around the project. In fact the community seems non-existent, or nomadic. Unfortunately even their mailing list has been trolled by so many leech sites that you can go down this rabbit hole always looping back around to where you started.

These two factors make learning to use boost libraries a rather daunting task. Even if the technicalities of using boost aren't excessively complex, it is a massive set of libraries and staring it down when all you're armed with is a few code snippets and scattered pieces of the mailing list from the darkest corners of the internet... well you get the idea.

I got into tinkering with boost around version 1.45 and it's only now in version 1.52/1.53 that I feel comfortable enough to use it in production. There are so many things to get used to and remember, even simple things like how you've configured boost and remembering that configuration, because how the libraries are built and function can vary wildly based on your preferences at compile time due to how customizable things are.

*However*, **make no mistake**, once you can wield boost, you've gained a powerful weapon for rapidly building solid, cross-platform programs. Just take `boost::asio` for example. You can write an immensely powerful, scalable and rock solid cross platform asynchronous web server in just a couple hundred lines. I've written multiple clients, servers, proxies etc over the years with just a few hundred lines of code each that have yet to fail me, and can port them from platform to platform in minutes.

As others have pointed out, larger companies are usually stuck with legacy stuff or like to roll their own which I completely understand. There is also this really silly thing I've heard of and encountered where dev leads and or project managers forbid using boost because it's "too big". My guess is that they believe that boost is 1 single library or they've never heard of [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html).

**As for WHY I choose to use boost**

I'd say I use it because as you imply in your question, it's "the" C++ library. Boost is viewed in the C++ world as the swiss army knife of things that eventually you're going to need to use. So the idea is that if there is a need, there should be a highly performant, and portable version of it in boost. [Big companies contribute to boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html), [very educated people with impressive resumes contribute and maintain it](http://cppnow.org/participant/marshall-clow/), and when a new standard of C++ is being developed, people usually look to boost to see what parts of it should become ISO standardized C++.

So if I need to add some functionality that there is probably an existing library for, the first place I'll look is boost just because I'm pretty safe in betting that it's pretty well optimized, portable, it will be supported and maintained for a very long time and bugs will be found and dealt with. In the open source world those qualities can be very difficult to come by.

Comment: Very right as for documentation. For example, Boost.asio doc's will explain how to write an http server in surprisingly few lines, which is great if your game uses http (or any other vanilla TCP protocol for that matter) but it becomes much more difficult if you wish to use a custom protocol or proprietary network library. It took me 20 min to understand how to create a websocket server using boost.asio, but weeks to understand how to use ENet (http://enet.bespin.org) via a custom boost.asio io_service.

Answer (score 22):

We used a bit of Boost back at our old workplace. The main reasons for mostly avoiding it and limiting its use were:

- compile times - some of it is very slow to compile, and you end up being reluctant to have boost #includes in any of your headers
- complexity - it's not well known by most game developers and so makes for unreadable code
- performance - some of the concepts perform slowly by default, eg. shared_ptr

Comment: boost::shared_ptr? how so?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it allocates the reference count on the heap somewhere. This is very bad for cache coherency during use and also means double the allocation and deallocation time at the start and end.

Comment: (Worth adding that use of make_shared can alleviate the problem.)

Comment: I think this answer is fairly clear that there are more reasons people avoid it than just to dodge one or two bad classes.

Answer (score 16):

Same thing is (was?) being said for the "more standard" STL. [This article](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html) talks about EASTL, an in-house rewrite of (parts of) STL by Electronic Arts to accomodate the needs of game development which are rather different than those of "more generic" application development.

So, maybe, someone somewhere is re-writing (parts of) *boost* to accomodate their needs in game development!

Comment: +1 for the article. I think this answers the question beautifully.

Comment: My experience is that the more portable your codebase becomes, the more you end up rewriting "standard" components, like STL.

Answer (score 7):

I hang out at StackOverflow and don't use boost. I will add my reason, because it is one not mentioned yet.

Boost has many great ideas, really. I like to look at what they have done and try out new things and ideas. They are great, because it is breeding ground for many C++ improvements.

But the boost is a very unwieldy beast for many reasons. One of the reason is that they need (want to) to be compatible on virtually any compiler with any quirks. As a result they need to employ many tricks, such as MPL to pull it off. For example (a long time ago) I wanted to use their shared_ptr, getting it to run meant I need the sources and libraries of what felt like 90% of boost. I ended up writing my own; 50 readable lines of code. (My requirements where stricter, like no weak_ptr or thread safety.)

Often you need a really small subset of boost, but integrating the entirety of boost is just not worth the hassle.

**Edit**:

Just to make is clear, since it appears not to have come over clearly (i.e. downvote). I use **do** use third party libraries. But in most cases, all things being equal, integrating a third party library or boost, the other third party library is quicker and cleaner. The remaining is done in "2h" finger exercise. I do take a very hard look in the build it or buy question.

Comment: There are tools like BCP, y'know.

Comment: Come back to me when you invented a time machine to go back to 2003. Most of the useful bits of boost are in the C++11 standard. BCP still does not beat writing your own, for a number of reasons. Once you have used BCP, it "becomes" your code and you need to maintain it. (rerun BCP?) The resulting code is still more than the hand written one. It is just not worth the hassle to integrate boost into your build system, if the alternative is 2h finger exercise.

Comment: Are you implying that you don't have to maintain your own code? Also, I wish I was that good to be able to write all parts of boost I am using in 2 hours (which involves also testing them on all build targets I am going to use, and writing tests). You must be a really fast coder. Oh, and also "most of the useful bits" pretty much equals to "I can't C++" here, because standard still lacks *a lot*.

Comment: For starters a few features provided by boost, I found elsewhere in small well defined packages, for example sigc++. In many cases more elegant and/or more efficient. What I came to boost for most where features, such as threads, smart pointers and regular expressions, things that made it into the standard. Over the years I have acquired a collection of third party libraries and some code of my own. "I can C++" for over 15 years now, thank you very much.

Comment: Boost dependencies across itself aren't really that wide and are usually reasonable. And IMHO that means you have to maintain several small packages instead of one. Oh welp.

Comment: I don't maintain packages... they work out of the box... ^_^

Comment: @SeanFarrell you shouldn't be condescending. You say you've been doing C++ for 15 years and then in a snippy sarcastic comment to Bartek it seems you don't understand what Bartek means when he says "maintain" in conjunction with "packages". Maintaining doesn't mean fixing them. Simply updating to a new release or storing versions for multiple targets is usually what this means. Just FYI.

Comment: *Sigh* Boost also works out of the box, yet still you mentioned maintaining it. I fail to see your logic here.

Comment: Ok true, I was not clear. First Bartek mentions BCP; once I use BCP I actually create my own personal fork of a subset of boost. Yes it is automated, but it requires contiguous effort to keep up to date. (= maintenance) On the other hand I have third party libraries, that at most need a build to integrate. (= packaging) The later is also true for unmodified boost. Now I have the choice of one huge intertwined collection of libraries that I only use 10% of or a few libraries that I use 95% of. And boost is not alone, since I always need third party libs to get real work done.

Answer (score 6):

Who says they don't use boost? I've known one or two C++ engines that have used boost. I've never directly worked with them; but, that's mostly 'cause my experience lies in Unreal.

As for reasons I've encountered for not using boost, and these are subjective:

- We like rolling our own data structures specific to the platforms we're deploying to
- We like limiting the amount of non-internally developed code we have to use in our projects, especially when that external code is reliant on other externally developed libraries.

It basically boils down to: a general solution isn't always the "right fit."

I'm sure someone who's actually worked with the library could comment better.

Comment: True, edited my question to account for this.

Answer (score 4):

In our case (not games), we have a great reason for not using boost (nor std): We have a lot of code that dates back a decade. According to the seniors, std and boost were either incomplete, full of bugs or just too slow for the high-performance things we require. So some base classes were implemented, using the same concepts (such as iterators) and often optimized for our algorithms. Nowadays, all three libraries (ours, std and boost) are very similar.

But do we want to port over all our code? Not really. I assume many other companies face the same dilemma. Either rewrite a lot of tested and working code or not use std/boost.

Comment: This is true, and something I didn't think of, but I noticed that a lot of people starting on game development in C++ don't care to use boost / std.  Sometimes I feel it's because learning boost is like learning a whole new language.

Comment: @James This is pretty much one of the biggest reasons. I posted an answer even though you've already accepted one just to give my perspective as someone who persevered through learning my way around boost, but not after being tempted to run away from it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't personally use boost or any other general purpose code when making games, because games are not generally general purpose.  The kind of code you might need to implement a game is usually specific to game development, not always but like 98% (random figure) of the time.  You can tack on that last few bits of code from boost or some other lib, but its probably better just to write out those little part you need here and there.

On a side note, I think that it is rather fun to write out your own code in c++, which is why I have never use boost or anything like it.

Comment: It's fun, but boost is meant for people that want to do sh*t done, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This is my opinion, but it is a fallacy to say that "games are special". Yea, real time industry automation is also special. I do both and can attest, that the bits where boost would apply, very clearly are quite similar. Saying they are different is ignorance, because on the fringes they are very different but the core language use is same. A sort function is basically the same no matter what you sort. (Then again, just that you can, does not mean you would want to, see my answer.)

Comment: I think your throwing words into my text, I never said games were a special case, I just said that 98 percent of the time you wont need code from a general purpose lib to make a game.  I am also not ignorant for suggesting writing your own code for the small parts instead of using a whole lib.  It's a matter of preference.

Comment: You can add the entire networking/multiplayer layer to your game using boost::asio and invent your own communication protocol for it. That is a 100% perfectly valid reason to use boost is any game you ever write that requires any kind of network related function. "Rolling your own" can be great when you're new and you need to learn. Nothing wrong with that. But at the end of the day I'm not going to waste time trying to write my own cross platform asynchronous communications layer when it's already been done and well at that.

Comment: @Digital Architect Wow, did anyone read my post?  I said "usually specific", for those who do not know English very well, that means "most of the time, but not always".

Comment: @HaywireSpark There is no need to start insulting people. I read your post, and still disagree with you. Even if you go with "usually specific", that is entirely irrelevant. Almost everything in boost is designed to be as portable and mutable as possible. boost::asio is a very generic implementation and is not geared toward any specific way of network communication. I can't imagine any scenario where I'd have to say "gee, boost::asio just doesn't fit my networking layer model I better reinvent the wheel". Just saying.

Comment: @Digital Architect You can disagree with my recommendation all you want, but that does not change the fact, that I have a completely valid idea.  Saying I said one thing, when I didn't, does not help your crusade either.  Your just nitpicking an idea because you can.

Comment: @HaywireSpark sigh. Have a good day buddy. You should try to be more open to criticism. Being able to accept criticism is part of being teachable, and if you're not teachable you're never gonna learn a thing. I'm not picking on you. Every person that has posted on your comment has disagreed with you. That's usually a good indication that you've said something disagreeable.

Answer (score 0):

legacy in house libraries is not a factor... the main reason why anyone shouldn't use boost u other general purpose library is because they're not optimized speed and memory, tho i have to mention that Cryengine uses the STL but they compile it agianst an open source version called STLPort, so dont be afraid of using the STL, just implement your custom allocators and you'll fine. dont use boost tho.

Comment: -1: For your belief that "Boost" is "not optimized speed and memory", when there are literally *dozens* of Boost libraries, all with varying degrees of speed and memory efficiency.

Comment: ... That actually _is_ the reason a number of game developers avoid boost and even roll their own STL, along with the fact that the heavy template usage drive compile times through the roof.  Especially keep in mind debug builds on MSVC, where you need the absolute minimum amount of abstraction and wrappers and genericism you can get away with, all of which are antithetical to Boost.  The problem is not algorithmic, but simply that Boost was never meant for bare tithe metal speed.  Nobody aside from game developers would want te trade offs that requires anyway.

Comment: @seanmiddleditch: My point is that there are *many* libraries in Boost. Some of them are faster and more memory efficient than anything you could code to do the same job, and some of them aren't. To denigrate the entire set of libraries for this is simply ignorant.

Comment: There aren't many game developers that can write a parser that is faster than Boost.Spirit. While there are many better (easier to use) options for parsing complete languages, Spirit is *very* fast at parsing well structured strings, even just converting strings to data types. The Boost.Xpressive library is also very fast for regex.

Bear in mind that many of the people working on Boost are also people that work on the C++ standard committee, and they know how to get optimal performance out of C++ across platforms.

Comment: They often use template metaprogramming in ways that allow a large part of the work to be done at compile-time, instead of at runtime, which will beat the hell out of any of the low-level runtime optimizations that game developers are so proud of. I've seen some performance increases of over 50x when converting certain tasks from some common high-performance C libraries to use the Boost equivalents.

Comment: @gerald In general boost is quite well optimized, that is true. Thake ublas for example, their expression templates bear most SIMD hands down. But saying that Boost.Spirit is fast is a really good joke. Spirit may be fast on a trivial grammar, but then you are not parsing. It is a recursive decent parser, one miss guess and you are off. Spirit is O(n^2), a "proper" LR1 parser is O(n), code efficiency is irrelevant with the wrong algorithm.

Comment: @SeanFarrell: Well, considering that you only get O(n^2) as a worst-case, it's hard to say that it's an a priori "wrong algorithm". And for small-to-medium-sized languages, it's far from an unreasonable choice.

Comment: What I was going at is that code efficiency is irrelevant if algorithm efficiency is poor. Then again, in most cases it does not matter. I still use XML for many use cases, even though it is grossly inefficient.

Comment: @Sean Farrell... you might want to read my post again. I never said nor implied that Boost.Spirit was the fastest parsing technology available, or that it was ideal for all scenarios. What I said was "There aren't many game developers that can write a parser that is faster than Boost.Spirit." How many game developers are able to write a "proper" LR1 parser that can beat Boost.Spirit in the most common parsing scenarios for game development?

I'm not sure what you mean by "Spirit may be fast on a trivial grammar, but then you are not parsing." What are you doing then, if not parsing?

Comment: @Gerald true that. I must apologize a bit, I am first and foremost working on compilers professionally, so I "know" how to develop parser for large and complex languages. In most cases I advice not to build their own parser, but use something existing and well established, i.e. XML, INI, YAML, whatever.

Comment: *"Spirit may be fast on a trivial grammar, but then you are not parsing." What are you doing then, if not parsing?* This might be snobbish, but one makes a distinction between reading and parsing.  You read data from a well defined format (e.g. binary) and parse data a lose format bound by syntactical rules (e.g. language). As an edge case, CSV. To read CSV you need lexing/tokenisation, but once you pass that step it is dumb reading. So if you have "linear" grammar, you are reading, not parsing...

Comment: @SeanFarrell Fair enough, not really my field. Though I do know that Spirit can also be very fast at parsing simple context-free grammars. I have recently replaced hand-written parsers with Spirit for very simple scripting languages and relatively complex text network protocols, with a fraction of the code originally used, and saw performance increase by orders of magnitude. Obviously one would not seriously consider using Spirit to implement a programming language or even a full-featured scripting language, but it is quite handy for simpler parsing without having to deal with code generators.