# Is it okay to use STL in my iPhone C++ 2d game?

Tags: c++

I've read a couple posts on the subject and it sounds hairy. But I think people are talking about using STL containers for Objective-C objects. I'm using pure C++.

Comment: It depends on your knowledge of memory allocations, pointers, references, copy constructors, etc...

Comment: "But I think people are talking about using STL containers for objective-c objects." No one is talking about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the STL efficient enough for mobile devices?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17833/is-the-stl-efficient-enough-for-mobile-devices)

Comment: I don't know. Is it?

Comment: The problem with this question is that you're asking "can I use this package of code" without giving any details about your use case, or seemingly doing any research at all (other than your note about STL containers for Objective-C objects, which shows you're misunderstanding what most people are getting at).  And "Okay" in what sense -- why would you be concerned about using the STL?  If it's speed related, do you have any specific use cases you're concerned about?  What would your alternatives be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: yes

Long answer: depends on your use case. But probably yes.